# Downcast from only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have this strange error and don't have any idea hot to fix it.

```
guard let theDialogObjects = dialogObjects as! [QBChatDialog]
```

> Downcast from '[QBChatDialog]?' to '[QBChatDialog]' only unwraps
>   optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

the code is from here: https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-services-ios/blob/master/QMChatService/QMChatService/QMChatService.m

```
- (void)allDialogsWithPageLimit:(NSUInteger)limit
                extendedRequest:(NSDictionary *)extendedRequest
                 iterationBlock:(void(^)(QBResponse *response, NSArray *dialogObjects, NSSet *dialogsUsersIDs, BOOL *stop))iterationBlock
                     completion:(void(^)(QBResponse *response))completion {
```

This is how I use it in Swift:

```
QMServicesManager.instance().chatService.allDialogsWithPageLimit(UInt.max, extendedRequest: ["type":String(QBChatDialogType.Private.rawValue)], iterationBlock: { (response, dialogObjects, userIDs, stop) in

      guard let theDialogObjects = dialogObjects as! [QBChatDialog]{
        return
      }
```

Comment: What type is dialogObjects?

Comment: just try by replacing '!' by '?'

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa dialogObject is NSArray)

Comment: @Shameerjan yea I had actually ? instead and it was with error replace with ! but not I replaced it as in my line of code above and it's still the same error

Comment: dialogObjects can't be NSArray if you're getting the said error message. could you provide minimum preproducible sample case?

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa I've added it to my question, thanks, yea it's an array)

Comment: what about this  - guard let theDialogObjects:[QBChatDialog] = dialogObjects as! [QBChatDialog]

Answer (score 3):

From the error message you aren't trying to change the type, just check the value isn't nil, so your check should be:

```
guard let theDialogObjects = dialogObjects else ...
```